Given the wave recording of some instrument, how can I automatically find out the closest Serum or Vital configuration to reproduce it?
Given the wave recording of some instrument, how can I automatically find out the closest Serum and Vital configuration to reproduce it?

I suspect this is not currently possible but perhaps some innovator could make an AI tool that does it

The end is nigh

@n00dles it never hurts to save human time

I'm not aware of any automatic way of doing this, but check out Eric Bowman's YouTube channel. He has many excellent examples of recreating sounds. In this tutorial he talks about the way this task may be approached:
Sound Design Tutorial Part 1 - How to create any sound with free software
